# Documenting C typedefs in doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

Following examples in the doxygen manual, I constructed the test header `test.h`:

```
/**
 * @file test.h
 */

  /** @brief This is a struct 
   *  @var foo A foo.
   *  @var bar Also a Foo.
   *  @var baz (unused field)
   */
  typedef struct {
     int foo;
     int bar;
     char *baz;
  } whatsit;
```

When I use the default `Doxyfile` (generated with '`doxygen -g`'), I see the warnings:

> ...test.h:11: warning: Compound whatsit is not documented
>
> ...test.h:7: warning: documented symbol `foo A Foo` was not defined
>
> ...test.h:12: warning: Member foo (variable) of class whatsit is not documented

What gives?  I am under the impression from the manual that you don't need tags like `@struct` when the comment directly precedes the definition, and also that it is legitimate to document the member vars in the block above, and not on the same lines they are declared with `/*< ...` syntax.   (I definitely hate the latter style...)

How can I get this to recognize the comment properly?

Comment: Please specify the version of doxygen you used.

Comment: Version is 1.8.13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation:
24.51 \var (variable declaration)

Indicates that a comment block contains documentation for a variable or enum value (either global or as a member of a class). This command is equivalent to \fn, \property, and \typedef.

indicating that at the \var line only the name of the variable should reside. As the variable `foo` does not exist but the structure member `whatsit::foo` you have to use the full qualified name.

Similar reasoning for the struct.

The result should be like:

```
/**
 * @file test.h
 */

  /** @struct whatsit
   *  This is a struct
   *
   *  @var whatsit::foo
   *    A foo.
   *  @var whatsit::bar
   *    Also a Foo.
   *  @var whatsit::baz
   *    (unused field)
   */
  typedef struct {
     int foo;
     int bar;
     char *baz;
  } whatsit;
```

Comment: Ok, so the answer seems to be "You must use the `@struct` tag even though the comment block comes directly before" and also "you must qualify the variable names with the name of the struct even though the comment block comes directly before" and also "you must put a newline between the `@var` line and the doc string".   If I relax any one of these, more warnings occur.   It's maybe particular of me but just don't think I can live with those (esp since syntax is javadoc-like) - too much typing / lexical real-estate. would a newer version help?  Or time to find a new doc system. =/